# How does `activity` work in a Runnable? My Android table is not displaying

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using JSoup to parse a website (I had to set it up to use cleartext requests since https is not supported). It is in a `Runnable` to avoid blocking the main network thread. However, it does not seem to display when I run my code. I suspect it has something to do with `activity` (as I had trouble setting it up) and that I am using an inner class but no errors or warnings are returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.investmenthuntermobile


import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TableRow
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.investmenthuntermobile.databinding.InsiderFragmentBinding
import org.jsoup.Jsoup


class InsiderFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: InsiderFragmentBinding


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = InsiderFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupData()

    }

    private fun setupData() {
        val thread = Thread(Task()).start()
    }


    inner class Task() : Runnable {

        override fun run() {
            val doc = Jsoup.connect("http://openinsider.com/search?q=GME").get()
            val table = doc.select(".tinytable")
            // Get the table header cells
            val tableHeaderRow = TableRow(activity)
            tableHeaderRow.isClickable = true
            table.select("thead").select("tr").forEach {row ->
                row.getElementsByTag("th").forEach { cell ->
                Log.d("CELL text", cell.text())
                val textView = TextView(activity)
                textView.text = cell.text()
                tableHeaderRow.addView(textView)

                }
            }
            // Get the table body cells
            table.select("tbody").select("tr").forEach {row ->
                val tableRow = TableRow(requireActivity())
                tableRow.isClickable = true

                row.getElementsByTag("td").forEach { cell ->
                    val textView = TextView(activity)
                    textView.text = cell.text()
                    tableRow.addView(textView)
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you have only created `TableRow` inside some `Thread` using `Activity`s `context`. at next you should add this `View` to layout used by `Activity` (and you are using only `InsiderFragmentBinding`, no source). when you fix this then yet another problem will occur - only main thread can draw and, generally, create `View`s, you can't do that in another thread (luckily you have a bug and you are drawing only in memory, not on screen/activity currently...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do your `openinsiderGetData()` work on a background thread properly using a coroutine.

```
private fun setupData() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            openinsiderGetData()
        }

        for (row in data) {
            val tableRow = TableRow(activity)
            tableRow.isClickable = true
            for (cell in row) {
                val textView = TextView(activity)
                textView.text = cell
                tableRow.addView(textView)
            }
            binding.table.addView(tableRow)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I will use this from now on.

Comment: is there a way to specify that I only want one `thread` or `worker` doing it. I changed my code quite a bit and it breaks I think because there are multiple threads working through the code. My table for example, ends up out of order.

Comment: Yes, although limiting it to a single thread might not be (and probably isn’t) the best solution, depending on what you’re doing exactly. You can create a single threaded dispatcher and use in `withContext` blocks to guard the bits of code that must always be done on the same thread.

Comment: Ok, just saw your other question. This definitely isn’t a parallelism problem because you aren’t doing anything in parallel. You’re calling this function only once, so it is processed on a single thread. Your issue seems to be trying to iterate a HasMap’s keys, but a HashMap’s keys come in random order. You can use a LinkedHashMap if you need to keep the keys in order.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew that about a HashMap!

Answer (score 0):

Your run() method currently updates the UI by creating TextView elements and adding them to the table rows. UI updates should always be performed on the main thread. You can use the runOnUiThread() method to execute code that updates the UI on the main thread.

This is not how I would implement it, but if you want a fast fix, you should use the code below:

```
inner class Task() : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            // Update UI elements here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following what @snachmsm said, I updated my code to use async code instead of a Runnable. I separated getting the data and drawing the UI which makes more sense.

```
class InsiderFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: InsiderFragmentBinding
    private val data = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = InsiderFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupData()
        //val jsonData = finraGetBondInfo("Boeing")

    }

    private fun setupData() {
        val test = GlobalScope.async { openinsiderGetData() }
        runBlocking {
            test.await()

            for (row in data) {
                val tableRow = TableRow(activity)
                tableRow.isClickable = true
                for (cell in row) {
                    val textView = TextView(activity)
                    textView.text = cell
                    tableRow.addView(textView)
                }
                binding.table.addView(tableRow)
            }
        }
    }


    private fun openinsiderGetData() {
        val doc = Jsoup.connect("http://openinsider.com/search?q=GME").get()
        val table = doc.select(".tinytable")

        table.select("thead").select("tr").forEach {row ->
            val arrayData = ArrayList<String>()
            row.getElementsByTag("th").forEach { cell ->
                arrayData.add(cell.text())
            }
            data.add(arrayData)
        }
        // Get the table body cells
        table.select("tbody").select("tr").forEach {row ->
            val arrayData = ArrayList<String>()
            row.getElementsByTag("td").forEach { cell ->
                arrayData.add(cell.text())
            }
            data.add(arrayData)
        }
        Log.d("DATA:", data.toString())
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You’re doing the long-running actions on the main thread by using `runBlocking` instead of `lifecycleScope.launch` for your coroutine. It causes UI jank and possibly the ANR crash.

Comment: You have the right idea about separating the HTTP request to get the data from the UI rendering that displays that data on the screen. But as mentioned, you shouldn't block the main thread or it will cause your app to crash. Once you get this version working, I recommend that you learn about LiveData. This will provide an even clearer separation between your network request and UI rendering. Also, you should look at RecyclerView. This is the recommended way for rendering a list of data. You should also learn about Jetpack Compose which makes this kind of thing even easier.